# What is the minimum number of 8x1 MUX required to implement 22x1 MUX?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

How to implement this? It is an MCQ type question and the options are: 4, 3, 2 and 6

How to implement this? It is an MCQ type question and the options are: 4, 3, 2 and 6

I personally felt, using *6 select lines* instead of using 5 select lines, will be  a good option,  because It helps me in implementing this using 3 8x1mux only.

I have two stages in this design
The first stage consists of 2 8x1 mux whose select lines are connected to S[2:0]. Together these mux can handle inputs I[15:0]

The remaining 6 inputs and the 2 outputs corresponding to muxes in the first stage will be connected directly to 2nd stage mux. The select lines of 2 stage mux will be connected to S[5:3].

So the following are the select line combinations and their corresponding output

- S[5:0]       Y
- 000 000   I0
- 000 001   I1
- ...........
- 000 111   I7
- 001 000   I8
- 001 001   I9
- ...........
- 001 111   I15
- 010 xxx   I16
- 011 xxx   I17
- 100 xxx   I18
- 101 xxx   I19
- 110 xxx   I20
- 111 xxx   I21

Is there any serious drawback in this design or is it fine?

Comment: Welcome! Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

The number of 8x1 MUX required to implement a 22x1 MUX is: 22/8 = 2.75. Rounded up its 3, so you will need 3 8x1 MUX units.

A 22x1 MUX will require 5 selector lines, log2(22), An 8x1 MUX has only 3. To accommodate the 2 extra lines we will have to use the 8x1 enable inputs and activate them with some additional logic.

Writing out a truth table at this point will help you visualise what you need to implement and how to use the additional 2 selector lines to enable your 8x1 MUX units. For an example look at website [1].

You have 5 selector lines, S4, S3, S2, S1, and S0. S2..0 connect to the 8x1 MUX units as normal.

S4 and S3 need to go through some combinatorial logic using AND gates and NOT gates:

- Enable MUX_1 when NOT(S4) AND NOT(S3)
- Enable MUX_2 when NOT(S4) AND S3
- Enable MUX_3 when S4 and NOT(S3)

[1] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementing-321-multiplexer-using-81-multiplexers/

Answer (score 0):

If your 8x1 muxes have output enables, like [HC251](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mc74hc251a-d.pdf), then you can use 3 muxes and wire the outputs together as per SSB's answer, with some glue logic to control the output enables. Could be logic gates, or a 2 bit to 3 outputs decoder chip, or no extra circuitry if the microcontroller has enough available pins to control the output enables.

If they do not have output enables, or they're analog muxes that always keep one of the inputs connected to the output, then you can't wire all the outputs together, so you need three 8x1 muxes and one 3x1 mux to combine the outputs.

If the question doesn't say if the muxes have output enables or if they're analog, then the answer is either 3 or 4 but it's impossible to say which one.

If these are physical chips, then the cheapest solution will probably be to use four identical 8x1 muxes, because that's only one part to stock and manage, one BOM line, one slot on the pick and place machine, etc. The best solution will probably depend on what other chips are already on the BOM, if there are unused logic gates in some packages, etc.